# cannot read property '0' of undefined in ARRAY Javascript

Tags: javascript

ok, this is really making me nuts. i cant figure out why i keep getting `uncaught typeError: cannot read property '0' of undefined`

can someone please point whats causing the `uncaught error` on this ARRAY line `num = myArray[0];`

```
 var val= this.value;

 myArray = checkinput(val); 
 num = myArray[0];
 data = myArray[1];

 if (num == 0 ) { 
  ....
 } else {
  ....
 }

/*FUNCTIONS*/

function checkinput(val) {
var val;
//some regex here

if (regexA.test(val)) {
    var fname = val.match(regexA)[0];
    var arr = [0,fname]; // 0 as identifier
    return arr;
    }   

else if (regexB.test(val)) {
    var lname = val.match(regexB)[0];
    var arr= [1,lname]; // 1 as identifier
    return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: you function `ckeckinput` does not always return a value. Your input must not be matching either test.

Comment: Certainly both conditions inside your `checkinput` function are false therefore it isn't returning anything.

Comment: how can i go on debugging this properly?

Comment: Use Developer console of the browser. Set break point and run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because neither `regexA.test(val)` nor `regexB.test(val)` returns `true`. Try adding an `else` clause with an error:

```
...
} else {
    console.log("error, test(val) invalid: " + test(val));
}
```

I cannot help you any further since I don't know the contents of your regex variables. But if I were you, I'd start looking there.